# como extreaer datos de una cadena

Tags: javascript, html, html5, json

como puedo extraer los datos que estan dentro de los corchetes con su respectiva posicion?

```
let str = 'Aqui esta [pepe] y [pepito]';

resultado=str.split(" ")

[ 'Aqui', 'esta', '[pepe]', 'y', '[pepito]' ]
```

en este caso deberia obtener la palabra pepe en la posicion 2 y 4 en pepito para poder guardar un objeto con la posicion y la palabra

Comment: Para sacar las palabras de los corchetes puedes usar una regex. Mira aquí https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let str = 'Aqui esta [pepe] y [pepito]';
let objetoProcesado = [];
str.split(" ").map((valor, indice) => {

  let dato = valor;
  try {
    // Tenemos dos restricciones:
    // 1. Que tenga [ ] en la posición inicial y posición final de la palabra.
    // 2. Que solo exista 1 "[" y 1 "]"
    let condicionInicial = dato.toString().indexOf('[') == 0;
    //console.log('condicionInicial -> ',condicionInicial);
    let condicionFinal = dato.toString().indexOf(']') == dato.toString().length -1;    
    //console.log('condicionFinal -> ',condicionFinal);    
    //console.log('palabra procesada: ', dato);
    
    let cantidadBracketsApertura = 0;
    let cantidadBracketsClausura = 0;
    for(let index = 0; index <= dato.toString().length; index++)
    {
        let character = dato.toString().charAt(index);
        if(character == '[')
        {
            cantidadBracketsApertura++;
        }
        if(character == ']')
        {
            cantidadBracketsClausura++;
        }
    }

    let condicionBrackets = (cantidadBracketsApertura == 1 && cantidadBracketsClausura == 1);
    
    if (condicionInicial && condicionFinal && condicionBrackets)
    {
        let palabraSinBrackets = dato.toString().replace('[','').replace(']','');
        objetoProcesado.push({'palabra':palabraSinBrackets, 'posicion':indice});
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('error al procesar:', dato);
  } 

});

console.log('Objeto Procesado: ');
console.log(objetoProcesado);
```

Lectura sugerida:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: En caso de que sean varias palabras dentro de los corchetes como seria ?

Comment: `Aqui esta [pepe, alberto, julio, arce, escolar] y [pepito]` ¿Te refieres a un caso así? Sea como sea, ya tienes la parte más complicada resuelta en tu pregunta original, inténtalo, el código está entendible y además hay una lectura sugerida que si la lees, entenderás mejor cómo funciona ese `.map` En caso desees publicar otra pregunta, incluye lo que hayas intentado y lo que hayas investigado para resolver el nuevo escenario. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar remplazar los carácteres de esta manera. Esto en caso de que la estructura no sea cambiante.

```js
let str = 'Aqui esta [pepe] y [pepito]';

resultado = str.split(" ").map(x => {

  let dato = x
  try {

    dato = dato.replace('[', "[\"").replace("]", "\"]")
    dato = JSON.parse(dato)

  } catch (e) {
    console.log('ignorado', x)
  }

  return dato

})
console.log(resultado)
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
let str = 'Aqui esta [pepe] y [pepito]';
arr = str.split(" ")

for (x in arr )
 if(arr [x].includes("]"))
    arr [x] = [ arr [x].replace(/\[|\]/g,"")]
 
console.log(arr )
```